# If I want to perform login on the service layer with shiro, how could it set cookie?

Tags: java, shiro

It seems like the session of shiro uses cookie on the client, and I think it only works when on the controller layer, for the cookie should be set in the object `HttpServletResponse`. So, if I perform the `login()` on the service layer, how could it set cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Your best would be to take a look at the sample projects: https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/main/samples

Sounds like the "web" or "servlet-plugin" would be the best match for you.

Basically, though, you don't need to worry about calling the `login()` method or setting up the cookie manually. Shiro would take care of all that for you at the servlet level (using a Filter).